# How do I prevent default IIS compression on a response that is already compressed?

Tags: iis, httphandler, httpmodule, http-compression

## TLDR

I have an `IHttpHandler` that performs compression. It works fine on its own. But then I added an `IHttpModule` that performs a completely unrelated task on those (and all other) responses, and now IIS is re-compressing the already-compressed responses. How can I prevent this?

## The Whole Story

I have an `IHttpHandler` implementation that performs combination and compression (among other things) for CSS and JS files. Everything in the `IHttpHandler` works exactly like I want it to.

But then I added an `IHttpModule` implementation that removes unnecessary response headers (`Server`, `X-AspNet-Version`, etc.) from **all** responses (including the dynamic responses that are generated by the `IHttpHandler`) during the `PreSendRequestHeaders` event.

However, it seems that simply registering an `IHttpModule`, regardless of what it actually does, causes IIS to apply compression to the response, even if the response is already compressed.

So, my `IHttpHandler` explicitly compresses the response and sets the `Content-Encoding` header, then (if and only if) the `IHttpModule` is also registered, IIS re-compresses the response (so there's a doubly-compressed response that browsers can't read).

I don't want to disable all default compression. I still want HTML from views to be compressed (and I want any CSS and JS that doesn't go through the `IHttpHandler` to also be default-compressed).

I'm guessing there's no easy solution to my problem because it seems like a bug in IIS. IIS should not compress a response that is already compressed.

I tried adding the following to my web.config, but it had no effect:

```
<httpCompression>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/css" enabled="false" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

(From my interpretation of the [documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression/dynamicTypes), that should disable compression for dynamically generated CSS and JS.)

I also tried this, to no effect:

```
<httpCompression>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <clear/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <clear/>
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

(From my interpretation of the documentation, that should disable **all** default compression.)

## Update

In my `IHttpHandler`, I call `context.Response.Flush` at the very end. If I remove this call, the response doesn't get double-compressed. I'm fine with this as a solution. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

## Update 2

My best guess is that calling `Flush` puts the response into such a state that IIS doesn't think the response is already compressed (and so it applies default compression). Even though in my module I can check both...

- that `Response.Headers` contains a `Content-Encoding` header and
- that `Response.Filter` is non-`null` and is one of the `System.IO.Compression` types.

Not sure why IIS can't determine that the response is already compressed from those facts.

Comment: Did you get any further with this?